# Proteus 8.11 - Ground plane disappearing when I try to route or move a component

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, proteus, pcb-layers, ground-plane

I have a two-layers thru-hole PCB in Proteus 8.11, and I am trying to put a ground plane on the bottom layer. But, every time I move a component or try to route, the ground plane just disappears. I have to click *Regenerate* in the plane options to make it appear, but then when I try and do another connection it just disappears again.

Here is a short video showing exactly what I mean:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hTuJ37vytirPB94QvFdjKVpGn122QMty/view?usp=sharing

To insert the ground plane, I just selected a zone with the *Zone Mode* tool. Here are some screenshots of the configuration and the design rules:

[image: Ground Plane configuration]
[image: Design Rules - GENERAL]
[image: Design Rules - POWER]
[image: Design Rules - SIGNAL]

I don't know if this is relevant, but I'm running the program on a VM with WIN7.

Comment: So what if the GP disappears? Live with it and re-flood it when you need to check it.

Comment: @Andyaka Well yeah that's an option, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Auto Zone Regeneration (on the Tools menu)

Comment: This saved me. Thanks.